# How to download a string as a .csv file, without writing the string to a file and reading from the file?

Tags: perl, download, cgi

I am re-designing a website where, based on the options selected by the user, I need to fetch data from a DB and then give it in a downloadable format to the user. I am fetching the data into a string variable, but I dont want to write it to a file and then write the download code. I want to download the string to a file on the client side. I am using perl for this.

Previously I was reading and downloading from a file using this perl-cgi code :

```
...
my $ID = "details.csv";
my @fileholder;
my $filesloc = "/html/details.csv";

open(DLFILE,'<',"$files_loc") || Error('open','file');
@fileholder = <DLFILE>;
close(DLFILE)

print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$ID\n\n";
print @fileholder;
```

Which is saved as **downloadscript.cgi**. But now, I want to do this in a **.pm** file, and I am storing string values in @fileholder. I tried with :

```
my $ID = "details.txt";
my @fileholder = qw(name age address);
print "Content-Type:text/plain\n";
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$ID\n\n";
print @fileholder;
```

in the .pm file, but it is PRINTING the above lines on the screen instead of opening the 'save as' dialog. Both are perl, so where am I going wrong?

EDIT : I got to know the reason, Its because I am previously opening a html content type, and then in the middle, I am opening this "Content-Type:text/plain\n" - this is where the browser gets confused. Now, could someone please tell me how to close the previous html content-type and open this new content type for downloading?

Comment: So, you changed the Content-Type, and now browsers are behaving differently?  Have you tried changing it back?

Comment: shouldn't it be `text/csv` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the browser is viewing the content-type you create and send with `print "Content-Type:text/plain\n";` - as @Julian mentions you could try changing that line back or *adding* the line `print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";` after the `text/plain` line and see if this fixes things.  Since that particular content-type may actually need a real file to to work with, you could try other content-types (see @Hunter McMillen's suggestion) since the browser may offer a download/save dialog in that case.

You might need to add the following to fool the browser (and remove the `text/csv`):

```
print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";     
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$ID\n\n";
```

Comment: I first start off my perl script with print "Content-type:text/html\n" - this is because I use that perl script to print a html page. But, In the same file, I also want a download code, where I would have to use print "Content-type:text/csv" as Julian told. But when I do that, the browser takes only the first Content-type into account, which is actually the html format and LITERALLY PRINTS the line "Content-type:text/csv" on the page. So, in order to close the html content-type and open this text/csv content type, what do I have to do?

Comment: Edited response slightly. What if you add the two lines mentioned at the end?

Comment: I did, and it PRINTS those lines on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like there can be only one content-type set for one response. So, I am now navigating to another page from my current page, where I am writing the download code. Thanks for your help people!